# boost::python string-convertible properties

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I have a C++ class, which has the following methods:

```
class Bar {
...
    const Foo& getFoo() const;
    void setFoo(const Foo&);
};
```

where class `Foo` is convertible to `std::string` (it has an implicit constructor from `std::string` and an `std::string` cast operator).

I define a Boost.Python wrapper class, which, among other things, defines a property based on previous two functions:

```
class_<Bar>("Bar")
    ...
    .add_property(
        "foo",
        make_function(
            &Bar::getFoo,
            return_value_policy<return_by_value>()),
        &Bar::setFoo)
    ...
```

I also mark the class as convertible to/from `std::string`.

```
implicitly_convertible<std::string, Foo>();
implicitly_convertible<Foo, std::string>();
```

But at runtime I still get a conversion error trying to access this property:

```
TypeError: No to_python (by-value) converter found for C++ type: Foo
```

How to achieve the conversion without too much boilerplate of wrapper functions? (I already have all the conversion functions in class `Foo`, so duplication is undesirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up giving up and implementing something similar to [custom string class conversion example in Boost.Python FAQ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#custom_string), which is a bit verbose, but works as advertised.